# seaborn don't give color in heatmap if cell value is higher than 0.05

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I have created heatmap and I want to put a condition that if cell value is higher than 0.05 it will get specific color that is not in the cmap.
Right now what I do is to define vmin and vmax but the problem is that the vmax still get the 0.5 or 0.6 values and I can't be sure that the condition is really kept.

```
green=sns.light_palette("seagreen",reverse=True,as_cmap=True)
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(18.7,3.27)})
sns.heatmap(fhtmp,square=True,cmap=green,linewidths=.5,vmin=0, vmax=0.05)
```

[image]

as you can see here, I can't really know if the ones that are purple are equal to 0.05 or more than 0.05, **I would like to be able to distinguish so if value is greater than 0.05 the cell will have different color such as white or gray.**

Edit: I have managed to use kind of mask but green has one tone and the mask has serveral colores.

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(18.7,3.27)})
ax = sns.heatmap(fhtmp, cmap=green, center=0.8, square=True, 
                 linewidth=.5, vmin=0, vmax=0.05)
ax = sns.heatmap(fhtmp, mask=fhtmp < 0.053, cmap='Blues', square=True, annot=False, vmin=0.053, vmax=0.53, cbar=False, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]
so this is what I get this is still not the desired results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`set_over()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_over) on your colormap. E.g. `green.set_over('lightgrey')`.  Similar functions are `set_under()` and `set_bad()`.

The [`extend` keyword](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) can show these extra colors in the colorbar (default as little triangles).

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

green = sns.light_palette("seagreen", reverse=True, as_cmap=True)
green.set_over('tomato')
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (18.7, 3.27)})
sns.heatmap(np.random.uniform(0, 0.07, (1, 20)), square=True, linewidths=.5, annot=True, fmt='.3f',
            cmap=green, vmin=0, vmax=0.05, cbar_kws={'extend': 'max'})
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]